# Parse Foursquare json response using php

Tags: php, json, foursquare

I have a json response which was listing the near by places in  foursquare  , But i cant parse  and show it using php  , 
Here is the response i got

```
     "{"meta":{"code":200},"response":{"neighborhoods":[],"venues":[{"id":"4c8a4a729ef0224b4861597b","name":"Domino's Pizza","contact":{},"location":{"address":"Landship Mall","lat":11.258859817080253,"lng":75.78049986984433,"distance":15,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":
[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d1ca941735","name":"Pizza Place","pluralName":"Pizza Places","shortName":"Pizza","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/food\/pizza_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":230,"usersCount":113,"tipCount":8},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},
    {"id":"4dd4947b22716ea3ce61c577","name":"KFC","contact":{},"location":{"address":"Holiday City Centre","crossStreet":"Bank Road","lat":11.259231792131327,"lng":75.7804848253727,"distance":53,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":{"id":"4ffaf6ede4b024f55b8a67a7","name":"Dubai Bazar","contact":{},"location":{"address":"Opp Gulf Bazar","crossStreet":"Bank Road","lat":11.258383964520572,"lng":75.780664493572,"distance":49,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":44,"usersCount":24,"tipCount":0},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"4cc1a3cb53f6b71336237df8","name":"Shoe Factory","contact":{},"location":{"address":"Focus Mall, Rajaji Road","lat":11.258749384434863,"lng":75.78040904287909,"distance":0,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d107951735","name":"Shoe Store","pluralName":"Shoe Stores","shortName":"Shoes","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/shops\/apparel_shoestore_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":5,"usersCount":4,"tipCount":0},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"5076a3e2e4b0abe31a24b39d","name":"Nike","contact":{},"location":{"lat":11.258749384434863,"lng":75.78040904287909,"distance":0,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d107951735","name":"Shoe Store","pluralName":"Shoe Stores","shortName":"Shoes","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/shops\/apparel_shoestore_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":9,"usersCount":5,"tipCount":0},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"4fb62920e4b0aced0a7e65d9","name":"4in Bazar","contact":{},"location":{"lat":11.258903822420683,"lng":75.78080641042673,"distance":46,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4f04afc02fb6e1c99f3db0bc","name":"Mobile Phone Shop","pluralName":"Mobile Phone Shops","shortName":"Mobile Phone","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/shops\/mobilephoneshop_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":51,"usersCount":23,"tipCount":0},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"4daa61f190a0fde2ea426783","name":"Dakshin","contact":{},"location":{"address":"Opp. Canon Showroom","crossStreet":"Marovar Rd.","lat":11.25928769956318,"lng":75.781345693192,"distance":118,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d1d3941735","name":"Vegetarian \/ Vegan Restaurant","pluralName":"Vegetarian \/ Vegan Restaurants","shortName":"Vegetarian \/ Vegan","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/food\/vegetarian_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":74,"usersCount":47,"tipCount":4},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"4bb6af382f70c9b613de8530","name":"Paragon Restaurant","contact":{"phone":"+914952767020","formattedPhone":"+91 495 276 7020"},"location":{"address":"Kannur Road","lat":11.25674153640481,"lng":75.77957153320312,"distance":241,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d10f941735","name":"Indian Restaurant","pluralName":"Indian Restaurants","shortName":"Indian","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/food\/indian_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":801,"usersCount":442,"tipCount":54},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"4fe84256e4b09e82668f7576","name":"iceberg","contact":{},"location":{"address":"Land ship mall","crossStreet":"Mavoor road","lat":11.25932645611658,"lng":75.77995490718878,"distance":80,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d1c9941735","name":"Ice Cream Shop","pluralName":"Ice Cream Shops","shortName":"Ice Cream","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/food\/icecream_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":5,"usersCount":5,"tipCount":1},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"50daefa0e4b0ce6f80dddeff","name":"KFC","contact":{},"location":{"lat":11.257809755419688,"lng":75.78060205011138,"distance":107,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4d4ae6fc7a7b7dea34424761","name":"Fried Chicken Joint","pluralName":"Fried Chicken Joints","shortName":"Fried Chicken","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/food\/friedchicken_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":7,"usersCount":7,"tipCount":0},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"5296fa4a498e02ea46ee7438","name":"ISTP","contact":{},"location":{"lat":11.259023,"lng":75.780433,"distance":30,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d124941735","name":"Office","pluralName":"Offices","shortName":"Office","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/building\/default_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":6,"usersCount":1,"tipCount":0},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"4d380ede803ba35d512898fc","name":"Hotel Top Form","contact":{},"location":{"address":"Opposite KSRTC Bus Stand","crossStreet":"Mavoor Road","lat":11.258425121582624,"lng":75.78210353851318,"distance":188,"postalCode":"673004","cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d10f941735","name":"Indian Restaurant","pluralName":"Indian Restaurants","shortName":"Indian","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/food\/indian_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":93,"usersCount":46,"tipCount":2},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"506d5a88e4b08206c603ad36","name":"Seema Towers","contact":{},"location":{"address":"Mavoor Road Junction","lat":11.258742332458496,"lng":75.78060150146484,"distance":20,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d130941735","name":"Building","pluralName":"Buildings","shortName":"Building","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/building\/default_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":2,"usersCount":1,"tipCount":0},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"4b7076b5f964a520021c2de3","name":"Kozhikode","contact":{},"location":{"address":"Kozhkode","crossStreet":"Kozhikode","lat":11.258728111538751,"lng":75.78423507888425,"distance":417,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d1f6931735","name":"General Travel","pluralName":"General Travel","shortName":"Travel","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/travel\/default_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":408,"usersCount":154,"tipCount":0},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"4ffc5068e4b0f784b8a336d2","name":"Topform","contact":{},"location":{"address":"Mavoor Road","crossStreet":"Opp KSRTC Bus Station","lat":11.259024391394611,"lng":75.78207230254803,"distance":183,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":33,"usersCount":18,"tipCount":0},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"506d5b0ee4b0b0397364afc2","name":"Seema Towers","contact":{},"location":{"address":"Mavoor Road","crossStreet":"Junction","lat":11.258676528930664,"lng":75.7806625366211,"distance":28,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d130941735","name":"Building","pluralName":"Buildings","shortName":"Building","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/building\/default_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":3,"usersCount":2,"tipCount":0},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"4bd80d9809ecb71328f6477c","name":"Chick King Mavoor Road","contact":{"twitter":"chickingglobal"},"location":{"lat":11.258593479558789,"lng":75.78019380569458,"distance":29,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4d4ae6fc7a7b7dea34424761","name":"Fried Chicken Joint","pluralName":"Fried Chicken Joints","shortName":"Fried Chicken","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/food\/friedchicken_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":true,"stats":{"checkinsCount":64,"usersCount":21,"tipCount":1},"url":"http:\/\/chickingindia.in","specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"storeId":"","referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"4e8c31f7d22db1c42b23394e","name":"Thomas Cook","contact":{},"location":{"lat":11.259018701910897,"lng":75.78039768950438,"distance":29,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4d4b7105d754a06375d81259","name":"Professional & Other Places","pluralName":"Professional & Other Places","shortName":"Professional","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/building\/default_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":13,"usersCount":8,"tipCount":0},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"5083e907e4b0ba1a32517a8d","name":"sree theatre","contact":{},"location":{"lat":11.258712886520483,"lng":75.78254913793394,"distance":233,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d17f941735","name":"Movie Theater","pluralName":"Movie Theaters","shortName":"Movie Theater","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/arts_entertainment\/movietheater_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":31,"usersCount":25,"tipCount":1},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"511f7ab7e4b0293c709a5a9e","name":"Regal Cakes","contact":{},"location":{"lat":11.258030658961067,"lng":75.78061340346989,"distance":83,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d16a941735","name":"Bakery","pluralName":"Bakeries","shortName":"Bakery","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/food\/bakery_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":5,"usersCount":5,"tipCount":0},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"51fa5ad3498e8a5a78220481","name":"Samsung Service centre","contact":{},"location":{"address":"Lanship Mall","lat":11.259926795959473,"lng":75.78023529052734,"distance":132,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4f04afc02fb6e1c99f3db0bc","name":"Mobile Phone Shop","pluralName":"Mobile Phone Shops","shortName":"Mobile Phone","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/shops\/mobilephoneshop_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":2,"usersCount":2,"tipCount":0},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"51bf06d6498e013b34cb1f77","name":"Sunny Diamonds Calicut","contact":{},"location":{"address":"Mavoor Road","lat":11.258648546129269,"lng":75.78077802706704,"distance":41,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d111951735","name":"Jewelry Store","pluralName":"Jewelry Stores","shortName":"Jewelry","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/shops\/jewelry_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":3,"usersCount":3,"tipCount":1},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"4d9c44837ca6a35db1dd7355","name":"Kairali Theatre","contact":{},"location":{"address":"Mavoor Road","crossStreet":"Opp KSRTC","lat":11.25876873393199,"lng":75.782594550745,"distance":238,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d17f941735","name":"Movie Theater","pluralName":"Movie Theaters","shortName":"Movie Theater","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/arts_entertainment\/movietheater_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":144,"usersCount":65,"tipCount":4},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"52e26892498e858e0a96d1a5","name":"G K cool bar","contact":{},"location":{"lat":11.259726647193744,"lng":75.78074964370172,"distance":114,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d112941735","name":"Juice Bar","pluralName":"Juice Bars","shortName":"Juice Bar","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/food\/juicebar_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":2,"usersCount":1,"tipCount":1},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"4dd493281f6ec4e0bb7df0ec","name":"Hotel Sagar","contact":{},"location":{"address":"Mavoor Rd","lat":11.259054622041496,"lng":75.78167706727982,"distance":142,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d10f941735","name":"Indian Restaurant","pluralName":"Indian Restaurants","shortName":"Indian","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/food\/indian_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":56,"usersCount":38,"tipCount":5},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"5031f88ae4b06ef10f10437e","name":"KINGSWAY","contact":{},"location":{"address":"Mavoor road","lat":11.258937636566808,"lng":75.78084047045095,"distance":51,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d130941735","name":"Building","pluralName":"Buildings","shortName":"Building","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/building\/default_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":4,"usersCount":1,"tipCount":0},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"51d56de1498ea03f1f5d0ca4","name":"jassvis digital Color Lab & Studio","contact":{"phone":"+914952368796","formattedPhone":"+91 495 236 8796"},"location":{"address":"Kashkand Chambers","crossStreet":"Bank Road","lat":11.259803771972656,"lng":75.7801742553711,"distance":119,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4eb1bdde3b7b55596b4a7490","name":"Photography Lab","pluralName":"Photography Labs","shortName":"Photography Lab","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/shops\/photographylab_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":2,"usersCount":1,"tipCount":1},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"4fb33952e4b0a07cee15dde9","name":"Konica Photo Express","contact":{},"location":{"lat":11.258443832397461,"lng":75.7807846069336,"distance":53,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4eb1bdde3b7b55596b4a7490","name":"Photography Lab","pluralName":"Photography Labs","shortName":"Photography Lab","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/shops\/photographylab_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":6,"usersCount":3,"tipCount":0},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"5076604ee4b0ccc5b2ae6e9c","name":"SBT Calicut","contact":{},"location":{"address":"Kannur Road","crossStreet":"Opp. KTC Honda","lat":11.258255398551059,"lng":75.77828594615717,"distance":238,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d10a951735","name":"Bank","pluralName":"Banks","shortName":"Bank","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/shops\/financial_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":9,"usersCount":6,"tipCount":0},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"4d28130f888af04dfb86c2af","name":"Kairali Theatre","contact":{},"location":{"address":"Mavoor Road","lat":11.25899674587286,"lng":75.78250372510846,"distance":230,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d17f941735","name":"Movie Theater","pluralName":"Movie Theaters","shortName":"Movie Theater","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/arts_entertainment\/movietheater_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":26,"usersCount":16,"tipCount":0},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"50829c5fe4b059457b119efe","name":"Chest Hospital","contact":{},"location":{"lat":11.257112436693024,"lng":75.78063611018419,"distance":184,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d196941735","name":"Hospital","pluralName":"Hospitals","shortName":"Hospital","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/building\/medical_hospital_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":6,"usersCount":4,"tipCount":0},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"4fc369b5e4b07c20ea7b6a8b","name":"Etihad Airways","contact":{},"location":{"lat":11.259284019470215,"lng":75.78036499023438,"distance":59,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d1f6931735","name":"General Travel","pluralName":"General Travel","shortName":"Travel","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/travel\/default_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":6,"usersCount":4,"tipCount":0},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"4f8f8038e4b0c387d4a5fa5d","name":"Thiruvannur Temple Pond","contact":{},"location":{"lat":11.259355543417287,"lng":75.7804431029978,"distance":67,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d15e941735","name":"Pool","pluralName":"Pools","shortName":"Pool","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/parks_outdoors\/pool_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":17,"usersCount":9,"tipCount":0},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"51604200e4b024efa6241e78","name":"sarbath kada","contact":{},"location":{"address":"Kannur Road","crossStreet":"Under C.H Overbridge","lat":11.256613909069925,"lng":75.77844489566465,"distance":320,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d120951735","name":"Food Court","pluralName":"Food Courts","shortName":"Food Court","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/shops\/food_foodcourt_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":8,"usersCount":8,"tipCount":0},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"5000278ae4b049e4abb65fd5","name":"Dxb","contact":{},"location":{"lat":11.258172704626334,"lng":75.78003914590747,"distance":76,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4f04afc02fb6e1c99f3db0bc","name":"Mobile Phone Shop","pluralName":"Mobile Phone Shops","shortName":"Mobile Phone","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/shops\/mobilephoneshop_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":1,"usersCount":1,"tipCount":0},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"4e81b10f775b16f4798ea69b","name":"bata","contact":{},"location":{"crossStreet":"palayam","lat":11.259438482331458,"lng":75.78044128468439,"distance":76,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":6,"usersCount":4,"tipCount":0},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"4f642b73e4b045fbd37e7f7d","name":"Bhaskar's Sharbat Shop","contact":{},"location":{"address":"Kannur Rd.","crossStreet":"Nr. CH Flyover","lat":11.256604432352063,"lng":75.77813835002802,"distance":344,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d112941735","name":"Juice Bar","pluralName":"Juice Bars","shortName":"Juice Bar","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/food\/juicebar_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":66,"usersCount":28,"tipCount":1},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"4eae841293ad7677a972ada3","name":"Poonoor","contact":{},"location":{"lat":11.258429680362045,"lng":75.78105050708788,"distance":78,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d15f941735","name":"Field","pluralName":"Fields","shortName":"Field","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/parks_outdoors\/field_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":9,"usersCount":5,"tipCount":0},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"4fae661ce4b01d7a9004918d","name":"Nokia Care","contact":{"phone":"+914953043133","formattedPhone":"+91 495 304 3133"},"location":{"address":"1st Floor","crossStreet":"Lan Ship Mall","lat":11.257894624281441,"lng":75.78059069675197,"distance":97,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4f04afc02fb6e1c99f3db0bc","name":"Mobile Phone Shop","pluralName":"Mobile Phone Shops","shortName":"Mobile Phone","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/shops\/mobilephoneshop_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":8,"usersCount":5,"tipCount":1},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"504f49bce4b0b95082c4cbd8","name":"Techsys","contact":{},"location":{"address":"Lanship Mall","crossStreet":"Bank Road","lat":11.25937638888889,"lng":75.78000833333333,"distance":82,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d125941735","name":"Tech Startup","pluralName":"Tech Startups","shortName":"Tech Startup","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/shops\/technology_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":1,"usersCount":1,"tipCount":0},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"51d521bf498e19413f0f74f4","name":"United India Insurance Co.LTD","contact":{},"location":{"lat":11.258668899536133,"lng":75.78121185302734,"distance":88,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"503287a291d4c4b30a586d65","name":"Financial or Legal Service","pluralName":"Financial or Legal Services","shortName":"Financial \/ Legal","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/shops\/financial_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":2,"usersCount":2,"tipCount":0},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"50e6c51fe4b0092c6d1388ce","name":"Hotel Jinan","contact":{},"location":{"lat":11.258904217649036,"lng":75.7822653075384,"distance":203,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d10f941735","name":"Indian Restaurant","pluralName":"Indian Restaurants","shortName":"Indian","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/food\/indian_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":9,"usersCount":7,"tipCount":0},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"4fe6c823e4b0d55eff5bfbc1","name":"National Hospital","contact":{},"location":{"lat":11.259936439956475,"lng":75.78140245968072,"distance":170,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d196941735","name":"Hospital","pluralName":"Hospitals","shortName":"Hospital","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/building\/medical_hospital_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":10,"usersCount":8,"tipCount":1},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"4f619cd5e4b0bedb2a2dd2a5","name":"Gulf Bazar","contact":{},"location":{"address":"Bank Road","crossStreet":"Opp Dubai Bazar","lat":11.256599828110232,"lng":75.78060205011138,"distance":240,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d130941735","name":"Building","pluralName":"Buildings","shortName":"Building","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/building\/default_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":18,"usersCount":12,"tipCount":0},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"5159267be4b0172c3cd4df69","name":"Asoka Hospital","contact":{},"location":{"address":"Bank Road","lat":11.2578592300415,"lng":75.78089141845703,"distance":112,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d196941735","name":"Hospital","pluralName":"Hospitals","shortName":"Hospital","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/building\/medical_hospital_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":2,"usersCount":1,"tipCount":0},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"},{"id":"50efb1e2e4b04f50ee0c399a","name":"Kumari Banana Chips","contact":{},"location":{"lat":11.256672859191895,"lng":75.7783203125,"distance":325,"cc":"IN","city":"Kozhikode","state":"Kerala","country":"India"},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d1f9941735","name":"Food & Drink Shop","pluralName":"Food & Drink Shops","shortName":"Food & Drink","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/shops\/foodanddrink_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":3,"usersCount":3,"tipCount":0},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1395377160"}],"confident":true}}"
```

And i tried this but its giving `Trying to get property of non-object` error  ,

```
  $jsonurl = "http://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=$client_key&client_secret=$client_secret&v=20130815&ll=" . $lat . "," . $lng . "&limit=100";

    $newUrl = htmlspecialchars_decode($jsonurl);
    $json = file_get_contents($newUrl, 0, null, null);
    $json_output = json_encode($json, true);
    $json_output = $venues = stripslashes($json_output);
foreach ($json_output->response->venues as $items) {
        echo "{$items->name}\n";
    }
```

here is what i have tried : [Fiddle](http://codepad.org/KdhaApGu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems on your code...

### 1.

The first problem is ...

```
$json_output = json_encode($json, true);
               ^^^^^^^^^^^ //<--- Must be json_decode
```

You should be decoding it , instead of encoding it.

### 2.

Remove the `true` attribute from the above line, because in the below `foreach` you are accessing it as `object`.

The right way is

```
$json_output = json_decode($json);
```